# "We meet to discuss about something" - is the use of "about" appropriate here?

Tags: prepositions

> Teachers of various schools met to discuss **about** how to improve the standard of English.

Generally we meet in order **to discuss about something**. So in the above sentence becomes wrong when about is used in it?

Suggestions please.

Comment: Hi you cleared CGL ? I guess by this time you would have got your joining letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use ***discuss about***.
Never use it!

Because *discuss* is a transitive verb, we need its object. So, it's always ***discuss something*** i.e. ***discuss what***, ***discuss why***, ***discuss how*** (as it should be in your example sentence), and so on.

---

Here is a usage note in [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/discuss):

> #### Get It Right!: discuss
>
> The verb **discuss** is never used with the preposition **about**. It is simply followed by a direct object:
>   ✗ *I would like to <del>**discuss about the advantages**</del> and disadvantages of students using credit cards.*
>   ✓ *I would like to **discuss the advantages** and disadvantages of students using credit cards.*
>   ✗ J*ury members are not allowed to <del>**discuss about the trial**</del>.*
>   ✓ *Jury members are not allowed to **discuss the trial**.*
>
> Instead of **discuss something**, you can also say:
>   ▪  **have a discussion about something**
>   ▪  **talk about something**
>   *We **had a discussion about** the new plan.*
>   *We **talked about** the new plan.*

Comment: But when no direct object follows a verb, doesn't it become intransitive verb?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow you. What you said is correct, but how is it relevant to this question (the verb *discuss*)?

Comment: you said never to use it. But since it doesn't have a direct object, it becomes intransitive verb. if yes, then why you said that this is a transitive verb?

Comment: PS - I am not an English expert, but I am still learning it. So, pardon if it doesn't make any sense. @_@

Comment: "But since it doesn't have a direct object" -- Hmm... what do you mean by that?

Comment: What I mean is that if "Discuss" is a intransitive verb (in some other case), then will it be okay to use "about" after it? cause you said, "never use it."

Comment: Oh, I see! Hmm... do you have any example where "discuss" is used intransitively (that is, without an object)?

Comment: From NYT, 2006: On average, Keller Fay finds that people discuss about a dozen brands each day. [8th para](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/11/24/business/media/24adco.html?_r=0)

Comment: Thanks for the example! IMHO, the example you found is incorrect, and this can happen even in news and reports written by native speakers sometimes. Note that it's "We Talk About" the title, but somehow it's "people discuss about" that sentence for some unknown reason. The "talk about" alternative is mentioned in Get It Right! usage note above.

Comment: To me, the "discuss about" example from NYT above seems to be using "about" to mean "approximately". "Approximately 12 brands" are being discussed on average per person per day. I don't think it's incorrect, but uses "about" in a different way than the question example.

Comment: @ping Reading the sentence again, I think you're right.