# Should I write "discussed regarding monthly report to Peter" or "discussed to Peter regarding monthly report"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Which is the correct way of writing from following sentences.

1. I have discussed regarding monthly report to Peter in his office.
2. I have discussed to Peter regarding monthly report in his office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["We meet to discuss about something" - is the use of "about" appropriate here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69692/we-meet-to-discuss-about-something-is-the-use-of-about-appropriate-here)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discuss), the verb 'discuss' is transitive* and takes the preposition 'with' to introduce the participant with whom you are discussing. An object must follow its verb **immediately**.<sup>†</sup> So it should be

> I have discussed the monthly report with Petter in his office.
>
> <sup>(Note that a determiner should be used before a singular countable noun. A definite article is appropriate if your listener knows which report you are referring to.)</sup>

---

*Transitive verbs are verbs that take an object.

<sup>†</sup>The exception is when the object noun phrase is [heavy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with both sentences. You don't *discuss **regarding something** to* someone, you *discuss **something** with* them. The correct way of writing the sentence is:

> I have discussed the monthly report **with** Petter in his office.